# Peer credentials through unix domain socket ipc mechanism

Tags: unix, ipc

I'm writing a code for extraction of peer credential by the server process connected through ipc using domain sockets to the client process. There is no error in the code but while running it I don't get the euid and gid of the peer process.

Code for server process is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include<ucred.h>
#define SCM_CREDENTIALS
# define UNIX_PATH_MAX 100

int getpeereid(int connection_fd,uid_t euid,gid_t gid)
{
struct ucred cred;
socklen_t len = sizeof(cred);

if (getsockopt(connection_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PEERCRED, &cred, &len) < 0)
        return (-1);
    euid =cred.uid;
    gid = cred.gid;
//int passcred=1;
//setsockopt(connection_fd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_PASSCRED,(void *)&passcred,sizeof(passcred));

printf("effective user id", euid);
printf("effective group id",gid);
return 0;
}

int connection_handler(int connection_fd)
{
 int nbytes;
 char buffer[1024];
 char msg[256];
//while(cont=recv(connection_fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0)>0)
//{ 
//write(1,buffer,cont)

nbytes = read(connection_fd, buffer, 256);
buffer[nbytes] = 0;

printf("MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: %s\n", buffer);
printf("enter the message");
scanf("%s",msg);
nbytes = snprintf(buffer, 256,msg);
write(connection_fd, buffer, nbytes);
//} 
 close(connection_fd);
 return 0;

}

int main(void)
{
 struct sockaddr_un address;
 int socket_fd, connection_fd,res;
 socklen_t address_length;
pid_t child;
uid_t eid;
gid_t gid;

 socket_fd = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if(socket_fd < 0)
 {
  printf("socket() failed\n");
  return 1;
 }
printf("socket created\n");
 unlink("./demo_socket");

 /* start with a clean address structure */

memset(&address, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));

 address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
 snprintf(address.sun_path, UNIX_PATH_MAX, "./demo_socket");

 if(bind(socket_fd,
         (struct sockaddr *) &address,
         sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) != 0)
 {
  printf("bind() failed\n");
  return 1;
 }

 if(listen(socket_fd, 5) != 0)
 {
  printf("listen() failed\n");
  return 1;
 }

 while((connection_fd = accept(socket_fd,
                               (struct sockaddr *) &address,
                               &address_length)) > -1)
 {

// get the credentials
res=getpeereid(connection_fd,geteuid(),getgid());
if (res==0)
{
//if(res==0)
//{


child = fork();
  if(child == 0)
  {

   /* now inside newly created connection handling process */
   return connection_handler(connection_fd);
  }
}
  /* still inside server process */
  close(connection_fd);
//} 
}

 close(socket_fd);
 unlink("./demo_socket");
 return 0;
}
```

the code for client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#define UNIX_PATH_MAX 100

int connection_handler(int socket_fd)
{
int nbytes;
char buffer[1024];
char mesg[256];
printf("enter the message");
scanf("%s",mesg);
//printf("message is %s",mesg);
nbytes = snprintf(buffer, 256,mesg);
//fgets(buffer,256,mesg);
//i=atoi(mesg);
write(socket_fd,buffer,nbytes);
//send(socket_fd,mesg,sizeof(mesg),0);
}
//nbytes = read(socket_fd, buffer, 256);
//buffer[nbytes] = 0;

//printf("MESSAGE FROM SERVER: %s\n", buffer);
//}

int main(void)
{
 struct sockaddr_un address;
 int  socket_fd, nbytes,i;
 pid_t child; 
 char buffer[256];
 //char mesg[100];
 socket_fd = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if(socket_fd < 0)
 {
  printf("socket() failed\n");
  return 1;
 }
printf("socket created\n");
 /* start with a clean address structure */
 memset(&address, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));

 address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
 snprintf(address.sun_path, UNIX_PATH_MAX, "./demo_socket");

 if(connect(socket_fd, 
            (struct sockaddr *) &address, 
            sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) != 0)
 {
  printf("connect() failed\n");

 return 1;
}


child=fork();
while(child==0)
{
return connection_handler(socket_fd);
//printf("connection established\n");
//printf("enter the message");
//scanf("%s",mesg);
//printf("message is %s",mesg);
//bytes = snprintf(buffer, 256,mesg);
//fgets(buffer,256,mesg);
//i=atoi(mesg);
//write(socket_fd,buffer,nbytes);
//send(socket_fd,mesg,sizeof(mesg),0);
}

nbytes = read(socket_fd, buffer, 256);
buffer[nbytes] = 0;

printf("MESSAGE FROM SERVER: %s\n", buffer);

 close(socket_fd);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.thomasstover.com/uds.html for good overview.

If the server is Linux, the main problem is missing `_GNU_SOURCE`. Full patch below, it has a few minor changes just to get rid of `gcc -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c99` errors and warnings.

```
--- server.c.orig   2014-12-06 13:23:09.138472871 +0200
+++ server.c    2014-12-06 13:21:31.962475754 +0200
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+#define _GNU_SOURCE
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <sys/un.h>
@@ -5,7 +6,6 @@
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <string.h>
 //#include<ucred.h>
-#define SCM_CREDENTIALS
 # define UNIX_PATH_MAX 100

 int getpeereid(int connection_fd,uid_t euid,gid_t gid)
@@ -20,8 +20,8 @@
 //int passcred=1;
 //setsockopt(connection_fd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_PASSCRED,(void *)&passcred,sizeof(passcred));

-printf("effective user id", euid);
-printf("effective group id",gid);
+printf("effective user id %d", euid);
+printf("effective group id %d",gid);
 return 0;
 }

@@ -40,7 +40,7 @@
 printf("MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: %s\n", buffer);
 printf("enter the message");
 scanf("%s",msg);
-nbytes = snprintf(buffer, 256,msg);
+nbytes = snprintf(buffer, 256, "%s", msg);
 write(connection_fd, buffer, nbytes);
 //} 
  close(connection_fd);
@@ -54,8 +54,6 @@
  int socket_fd, connection_fd,res;
  socklen_t address_length;
 pid_t child;
-uid_t eid;
-gid_t gid;

  socket_fd = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if(socket_fd < 0)
```

Comment: You could have just told him that he was missing the formatting options for the `printf`, which is why he's not seeing any `euid` or `gid` rather than this wall of diff.

Comment: I made the changes and executed. my bad missed the format option! but after executing I get the same euid and gid i.e euid=1000 and gid=1000. what might be the reason for this?

Comment: @Neha isn't 1000 UID and GID of the user, who is running client? I have tried to run client from 2 different users (had to change permissions of the `./demo.socket` to be able to connect) and I've got correct results.

Comment: @Petesh Problem was not formating only: without `_GNU_SOURCE_` `cred` is undefined.

Comment: Okay!Got it. Thanx for the help. Appreciated